# Why the Officer package write to doc reverse in r?

Tags: r, officer

Why Officer write to doc reverse? I face that after i updated my R 4.0 to 4.2.

This is my code:

```
main.doc   <-read_docx()
body_add_par(main.doc," first ")
body_add_par(main.doc," second " )
body_add_par(main.doc," third ")
docx_summary(main.doc)
```

That is the result:

```
Content at cursor location:
  level num_id    text style_name content_type
1    NA     NA  third      Normal    paragraph

  doc_index content_type style_name     text level num_id

1         1    paragraph     Normal   **third**     NA     NA

2         2    paragraph     Normal  **second**     NA     NA

3         3    paragraph     Normal   **first**     NA     NA
```

Comment: Interesting, I got the expected result with officer 0.4.4, and then upon updating to 0.6.1, I got your result. Sounds like a bug introduced between versions. I have entered an issue here: https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/484

Comment: Does this happen if you assign the result of each `body_add_par()` back to `main.doc`?

Comment: Sorry for i couldnt get your question exactly Z.Lin, and what i have to do.. In the .docx result is same. At 0.3.12 version of officer (R 4.0.2) it was working. I updated to 0.6.1 (R 4.2.3) order comes reversed..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer in the comment from @z-lin that is correct:

```
library(officer)
main.doc <- read_docx()
main.doc <- body_add_par(main.doc," first ")
main.doc <- body_add_par(main.doc," second " )
main.doc <- body_add_par(main.doc," third ")
docx_summary(main.doc)
```

Results need to be assigned.

You can read more about this in first paragraphs of the doc: https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-word.html

[...] use one of the body_add_* functions: [...]

They all have the same output and the same first argument: the R object representing the Word document, these functions are all taking as first input the document that needs to be filled with some R content and are all returning the document, that has been augmented with the new R content(s) after the function call.

Comment: David thanx, yes for the above example it works. However when using in function it reversed again ```me_add_par=function(f.doc,a_par)
{
  f.doc<-body_add_par(f.doc, value = paste0("one-",a_par))
  f.doc<-body_add_par(f.doc, value = paste0("two-",a_par))
}

me_add_par(main.doc," function first")
me_add_par(main.doc," function second")
me_add_par(main.doc," function third") ```

Comment: In the version 0.3.12 it (par,fpar,img ..)  works in forward order, its logic was more understandable for me. Is there a way to make it..? Appreciated your kind interest.

Comment: See your call, instead of `me_add_par(main.doc," function first")`, use `main.doc <- me_add_par(main.doc," function first") `, this is R :) in the past it worked because of a side effect of a bug, it has been fixed. I think the manuals, guides and all my answers on SO show usage of assignment.

Comment: Thank you again @David, that was an interesting assigment for R :). 
To inform, I test two functions below, i found; me_add_par_1 works good with assigment, but me_add_par_2 gives error.
```me_add_par_1=function(f.doc,a_par) {  
  a<-5*5
  f.doc<-body_add_par(f.doc, value = a_par) }

me_add_par_2=function(f.doc,a_par) {
  f.doc<-body_add_par(f.doc, value = a_par)
  a<-5*5 }

main.doc<-me_add_par1(main.doc," text1") 
main.doc<-me_add_par2(main.doc," text2")```

Comment: I a little bit confused that body_add_* logic. Why the document cannot countinue from the last cursor position and need such assigments (pls no need to answer, just a wish)? 
Actually my script has function in function cases to make code simple. My script works on 0.3.12 besides i am trying 0.6.1. Thanks again your kind responds.

Comment: If you say something is not working and I disagree, I have to answer:) What is not working is your function, it returns `a`, not `f.doc`.

Comment: after using me_add_par_2 function i test with ```docx_summary(main.doc)```  gives: Error in x$doc_obj : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. and doc file not produced with ```print(main.doc, target="test.docx")``` 
I have functions including calculations and body_add_*..

Comment: As I explained to you in my previous comment, your R function is invalid, the last instruction is `a<-5*5`, not  `f.doc`.

Comment: As seen solution for me, converting my functions to ```me_add_par_1``` like, it works. Namely, i should put ```body_add_par``` at the last line of function.